# Codeigniter - Make encryption shorter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I always encrypt the post id of my user's comment.

So it's always like:

```
http://localhost/comments/V1r4AERSrvnGRmxQmsIHbM8Fsd~nJ6hv.gRR88wZIuwdSO08e.5O5ny0ChUOZ8biYbYEabI3jnGzFbcSE2YuEw--
```

I want it to be much shorter in lengh. So something like:

```
http://localhost/comments/V1r40239811
```

Is there a way of doing this?

How I decode:

```
$pid_encrypt = $this->uri->segment(3);
$pid = $this->encrypt->decode($pid_encrypt);
```

Thanks.

Comment: its not clear why you need to encrypt it at all

Comment: Because it would simply be /comments/1 or /comments/2

Comment: and so? whats wrong with this ?

Comment: I agree with @Dagon. No need to encode it. If you are worried about security then the encode function won't help you anyway, encryption/encoding are two different things. Regardless you don't need either for this question. `comments/{ID}` is normal. If you want to hide the ID from the url post the Id through an ajax post request .

Comment: What I want to do is show the comment ID (comments/1) as a litter bit bigger url that is not a number. For eg. (comments/alfwi)

Answer (score -2):

I would say encrypt it again with some other sort of encryption which is shorter and then decode it 2 times.